# How to add taxonomy term reference field in a custom form

Tags: 8, forms, entities

In the previous version of Drupal, it was possible to reference taxonomy tags in Drupal's forms using the following option:

```
'#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/'.$vid,
```

However, in the Drupal 8, taxonomy term reference field has been removed in favor of Entity reference, more info [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1847596).

So, is there any alternative available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I have found the way in the change records. take a look at: https://www.drupal.org/node/2418529

Here is the example options for taxonomy fields:

```
'#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
'#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
'#selection_settings' => [
  'target_bundles' => array($vid1, $vid2),
],
```